backshifting wish and would like

I wish I was smarter

"he said he wishes he was smarter"
Is my reported version correct? On average people change "wish" to "wished" but I think that if his "wishing" is still ongoing it is okay not to backshift. Yes or no?

I'd like you to do it when she comes

"he said he would like you to do it when she came"
I was told that "would like" doesn't change to anything in reported speech so, if I want to show that something probably already happened i backshift only second part. Correct?

You have two questions there. He said he wished he were or was smarter.

For 1, "was" is quite common but formal contexts would want it to be "were."

I would use "He says he wishes he was smarter" (here, says means has recently expressed the opinion). In (2), the tense depends on whether she has already come or not. (I'm sure this has already been explained.)
